# XSLT select the first success in <xsl:choose>

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I have a switch case with multiple tests. I want to ignore the rest of the cases if one succeed. My context : I need to retrieve a value from a matrix described in my xml like this

```
0 0 0 0 0; 0 0 0 0 0; 0 0 [value] 0 0; etc etc
```

I use substring to stock the values in between the `;` in variables. And another set of variables to stock each value between spaces from the first set of variables. Thing is I want to display only one value but I have to test each variable to know where it is. There may be multiple values in between a set and I want to set an order of cases so that when one succeed it ignores the rest.

This is a code sample, I apologize for the size and complexity, but it might help you visualize.

This is a sample of my XML element:

```
<projet>
    <Entree_Projet>
        <Generation_Collection>
            <Generation>
                <Index>1</Index>
                <COP>0 0 0 0 0 ;0 0 0 0 0 ;0 0 0 0 0 ;0 3.44 0 4.82 0 ;0 0 0 0 0</COP>
            </Generation>
        </Generation_Collection>
    </Entree_Projet>
</projet>
```

This is my loop :

```
<xsl:for-each
        select="$doc_RSET/projet/Entree_Projet/Generation_Collection/Generation[Index=$id_gene]/Production_Stockage_ECS_Collection/Production_Stockage/Source_Ballon_Base_Collection/*">
        <!-- Variables Cop -->
        <xsl:variable name="set1cop" select="substring-before(Performance_Ch, ';')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="set2cop"
            select="substring-before(substring-after(Performance_Ch, ';'), ';')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="set3cop"
            select="substring-before(substring-after(substring-after(Performance_Ch, ';'), ';'), ';')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="set4cop"
            select="substring-before(substring-after(substring-after(substring-after(Performance_Ch, ';'), ';'), ';'), ';')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="set5cop"
            select="substring-before(substring-after(substring-after(substring-after(substring-after(Performance_Ch, ';'), ';'), ';'), ';'), ';')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="set6cop"
            select="substring-before(substring-after(substring-after(substring-after(substring-after(substring-after(Performance_Ch, ';'), ';'), ';'), ';'), ';'), ';')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="set7cop"
            select="substring-before(substring-after(substring-after(substring-after(substring-after(substring-after(substring-after(Performance_Ch, ';'), ';'), ';'), ';'), ';'), ';'), ';')"/>


        <!-- 2eme / 3eme / 4eme valeurs des sets -->
        <xsl:variable name="set12cop"
            select="substring-before(substring-after($set1cop, ' '), ' ')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="set13cop"
            select="substring-before(substring-after(substring-after($set1cop, ' '), ' '), ' ')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="set14cop"
            select="substring-before(substring-after(substring-after(substring-after($set1cop, ' '), ' '), ' '), ' ')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="set22cop"
            select="substring-before(substring-after($set2cop, ' '), ' ')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="set23cop"
            select="substring-before(substring-after(substring-after($set2cop, ' '), ' '), ' ')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="set24cop"
            select="substring-before(substring-after(substring-after(substring-after($set2cop, ' '), ' '), ' '), ' ')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="set32cop"
            select="substring-before(substring-after($set3cop, ' '), ' ')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="set33cop"
            select="substring-before(substring-after(substring-after($set3cop, ' '), ' '), ' ')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="set34cop"
            select="substring-before(substring-after(substring-after(substring-after($set3cop, ' '), ' '), ' '), ' ')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="set42cop"
            select="substring-before(substring-after($set4cop, ' '), ' ')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="set43cop"
            select="substring-before(substring-after(substring-after($set4cop, ' '), ' '), ' ')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="set44cop"
            select="substring-before(substring-after(substring-after(substring-after($set4cop, ' '), ' '), ' '), ' ')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="set52cop"
            select="substring-before(substring-after($set5cop, ' '), ' ')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="set53cop"
            select="substring-before(substring-after(substring-after($set5cop, ' '), ' '), ' ')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="set54cop"
            select="substring-before(substring-after(substring-after(substring-after($set5cop, ' '), ' '), ' '), ' ')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="set62cop"
            select="substring-before(substring-after($set6cop, ' '), ' ')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="set63cop"
            select="substring-before(substring-after(substring-after($set6cop, ' '), ' '), ' ')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="set64cop"
            select="substring-before(substring-after(substring-after(substring-after($set6cop, ' '), ' '), ' '), ' ')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="set72cop"
            select="substring-before(substring-after($set7cop, ' '), ' ')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="set73cop"
            select="substring-before(substring-after(substring-after($set7cop, ' '), ' '), ' ')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="set74cop"
            select="substring-before(substring-after(substring-after(substring-after($set7cop, ' '), ' '), ' '), ' ')"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="format-number(Val_Cop_Ch,'&#160;##0,00', 'fr') != '0,00'">
                <xsl:value-of select="format-number(Val_Cop_Ch,'&#160;##0,00', 'fr')"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <!-- Tests Cop -->
                <xsl:if test="$set1cop and translate($set1cop, ' ', '') != 00000">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="$set14cop != 0">
                            <xsl:value-of select="$set14cop"/>&#160; </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="$set13cop != 0">
                            <xsl:value-of select="$set13cop"/>&#160; </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="$set12cop != 0">
                            <xsl:value-of select="$set12cop"/>&#160; </xsl:when>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:if test="$set2cop and translate($set2cop, ' ', '') != 00000">

                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="$set24cop != 0">
                            <xsl:value-of select="$set24cop"/>&#160; </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="$set23cop != 0">
                            <xsl:value-of select="$set23cop"/>&#160; </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="$set22cop != 0">
                            <xsl:value-of select="$set22cop"/>&#160; </xsl:when>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:if test="$set3cop and translate($set3cop, ' ', '') != 00000">

                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="$set34cop != 0">
                            <xsl:value-of select="$set34cop"/>&#160; </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="$set33cop != 0">
                            <xsl:value-of select="$set33cop"/>&#160; </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="$set32cop != 0">
                            <xsl:value-of select="$set32cop"/>&#160; </xsl:when>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:if test="$set4cop and translate($set4cop, ' ', '') != 00000">

                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="$set44cop != 0">
                            <xsl:value-of select="$set44cop"/>&#160; </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="$set43cop != 0">
                            <xsl:value-of select="$set43cop"/>&#160; </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:value-of select="$set42cop"/>&#160; </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:if test="$set5cop and translate($set5cop, ' ', '') != 00000">

                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="$set54cop != 0">
                            <xsl:value-of select="$set54cop"/>&#160; </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="$set53cop != 0">
                            <xsl:value-of select="$set53cop"/>&#160; </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="$set52cop != 0">
                            <xsl:value-of select="$set52cop"/>&#160; </xsl:when>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:if test="$set6cop and translate($set6cop, ' ', '') != 00000">

                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="$set64cop != 0">
                            <xsl:value-of select="$set64cop"/>&#160; </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="$set63cop != 0">
                            <xsl:value-of select="$set63cop"/>&#160; </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="$set62cop != 0">
                            <xsl:value-of select="$set62cop"/>&#160; </xsl:when>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:if test="$set7cop and translate($set7cop, ' ', '') != 00000">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="$set74cop != 0">
                            <xsl:value-of select="$set74cop"/>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="$set73cop != 0">
                            <xsl:value-of select="$set73cop"/>&#160; </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="$set72cop != 0">
                            <xsl:value-of select="$set72cop"/>
                        </xsl:when>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

So i'm calling this template containing this loop to get the values of this COP element. My if conditions determine if the "set" (each set contains the values between semi-colons) contains any value.

Comment: Could you please share the XSLT code for ease of understanding the requirement?

Comment: The way xsl:choose works is that it will break when the first xsl:when is true. It will not fall through the other conditions. The rest of cases should be ignored when one succeeds.

Comment: does it differ from xslt 1.0 to 2.0 ?

Comment: No, `xs:choose/xs:when` control flow and testing has not (and would not) change from version to version in XSLT.   Post a [mcve] and explain how the behavior varies from your expectations if you're still puzzled.  Be sure to post your actual high-level goal as well.

Comment: I added the sample of my loop, I will try to summarize it with a simpler example if you can't help me with the present sample.

Comment: You have to test the longest cases first, not the shortest ones. The shortest ones always match. Also, please state the highest XSLT version your environment supports. With XSLT 2.0+ the expressions could be shortened considerably.

Comment: XSLT 1.0. Thank you for the answers I think I see what's wrong with my loop.